# reading d3 data in from a file rather than hard coding it into a programme

Tags: d3.js, bigdata

Well, I'm currently using Dimple which is a kind of D3 for dummies.

I have my data arranged like so:

```
var data = [
          { "Location": "Farringdon", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Horsforth", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Old Bailey", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Caversham", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Newton Heath", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Hardham", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Boscombe", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Kings Worthy", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Caversham", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Lee", "Jobs": 3 },
          { "Location": "Wrexham", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Woolstone", "Jobs": 2 },
          { "Location": "Seacombe", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Painswick", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Northwich", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Royal Leamington Spa", "Jobs": 2 },
          { "Location": "Latchford", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Holborn", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Elton", "Jobs": 1 }
        ];
```

But it really lives in [this dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eghep1njby53x0x/cleaner_edsa_data.csv?dl=0) that is much bigger, and looks like this:

```
Location,Jobs
Farringdon,1
Horsforth,1
Old Bailey,1
Caversham,1
Newton Heath,1
Hardham,1
Boscombe,1
Kings Worthy,1
Caversham,1
Lee,3
...
```

what is the best (*i.e. the balance of ease and maintainability*) way to add this data into the program in a kind of *dynamic* way, rather than hard coding it as I've done.

---

**APPLICATION**

I'm currently using it to (attempt to) generate a simple bar chart:

```
<div id="chartContainer">
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.1.1.min.js"></script>
</div>

<script>
var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 1000, 1000);
var data = [
          { "Location": "Farringdon", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Horsforth", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Old Bailey", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Caversham", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Newton Heath", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Hardham", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Boscombe", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Kings Worthy", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Caversham", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Lee", "Jobs": 3 },
          { "Location": "Wrexham", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Woolstone", "Jobs": 2 },
          { "Location": "Seacombe", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Painswick", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Northwich", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Royal Leamington Spa", "Jobs": 2 },
          { "Location": "Latchford", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Holborn", "Jobs": 1 },
          { "Location": "Elton", "Jobs": 1 }
        ];
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg,data);
chart.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 300);
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Location");
var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Jobs");



var lines = chart.addSeries(["project"], dimple.bar, [x, y]);

lines.data = data;
lines.lineWeight = 5;
lines.lineMarkers = true;

chart.draw();

</script>
```

[image]

Comment: how are you currently using it ??

Comment: ah. ok- hang on I'll put it there

Comment: You want to read it from file, i.e same directory ? : d3.csv("nameOfCsv.csv", function(data){...  Or do you want to use file open and go to file browser and do it that way ?

Comment: the file lives in the same directory, I just improved the axis- I'm gonna put a new picture right now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is in the same directory just use the following D3 method :

```
d3.csv("nameOfCsv.csv", function(thisData){...
```

You can do all the work inside this function or just attach 'thisData' to a variable and use it elsewhere.

Example :

```
//set variable wherever you want, global if need be to be accessed by all functions. 
//I would recommend not naming it just data as it may conflict 
//but for the sake of this example 

var data;

d3.csv("nameOfCsv.csv", function(thisData) {
      data = thisData;
    }
```

Now you can use this data in your functions like so :

```
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
```

Comment: Is that what you need ? Or is it a way to parse the data to look like you need it to look ?

Comment: so all that kind of `chart', 'var', 'lines' all that lives in the function?

Comment: yeah I think that's what I mean, but thats kind of what was freaking me out- why does all that stuff have to live inside of a function about it? why isn't that data just put to an object and passed around that way?

Comment: You can do it either way. I prefer attaching it to a variable and using it elsewhere otherwise you're confined to being inside that function. It will work either way. So now you can get to your data by using thisData. For example, thisData.Location. Or even do var data;, then data = thisData. And then pass data to your D3/Dimple functions, and then use d.Location etc :)

Comment: yeah- that's what I'm saying- I think that way sounds much cleaner. but all the references I've seen do it in that crazy function way it makes the code look like a god damn minefield. do you have some example or documentation of the variable way?

Comment: @thisOneGuy it's generating the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`, but I can't tell where to put the missing `)`, it doesn't seem to be after the `function(thisData)` though

Comment: You don't need function(thisData){ because your using the variable. Unless you wish to have an update function then you would have : function functionName(passDataHere){ ... then when you want to update pass it the new data ... functionName(newDataPassedHere) ... As for your missing parenthesis, just go through your code and see where the missing bracket should be. Or you can send me a link to a fiddle (if its on JSFiddle) and i will take a look